# Overload a method with a function at runtime

Tags: python, metaprogramming

OK, I'll admit upfront this is a mega kludge and that I could definately implement this better. It's only morbid curiosity that's driving me to find out how I could do this.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def __(self, arg):
            self.doStuff(arg)
        self.overLoaded = __
    def doStuff(self, string):
        print string

SomeClass().overLoaded("test string")
```

This returns a parameter error because I'm only supplying overLoaded() with one argument instead of two. Is there some magic to tell the interpreter that it's now a method of a class (I tried decorating it with @classmethod, I always understood this to be it's purpose??)

Comment: It turns out that `classmethod` has a specific meaning in Python, so I don't think you mean classmethod in your title.  Perhaps re-phrase, something like "Replace a method with a function bound at run-time"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry about the self parameter, the function already has that from local scope.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def __(arg):
            self.bar(arg)
        self.foo = __
    def foo(self, arg):
        print "foo", arg
    def bar(self, arg):
        print "bar", arg

SomeClass().foo("thing") # prints "bar thing"
```

When creating an instance (after `__new__`, iirc, but before `__init__`) Python binds all the methods to automagically supply the instance as the first argument. If you're adding a method later then you need to supply the instance manually. As you are defining the function with `self` already in scope you don't need to pass it again.

Python's `new` module is not a solution as it has been deprecated since 2.6. If you want to create a "real" instance method do it with the partial decorator like this:

```
import functools

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def __(self, arg):
            self.bar(arg)
        self.foo = functools.partial(__, self)
    def foo(self, arg):
        print "foo", arg
    def bar(self, arg):
        print "bar", arg

SomeClass().foo("thing") # prints "bar thing"
```

Comment: What if the function you want to plug is defined outside the class init? In that case, self is not into scope. I always forget how to handle this case, because you are basically assigning an unbound method to an instance, it does not make it bound automatically...

Comment: sj26 Covered that in his second stanza with the partial() call.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are trying to add a new *instance method* (not class method) and it is not binding properly.  Python has a module function to manually bind functions to instances.

```
import new
self.method = new.instancemethod(func, self, class)
```

Edit: Apparently the `new` module is deprecated.  Use the `types` module instead for metamagic.

```
import types
self.method = types.MethodType(func, self, class)
```

Answer (score 0):

sj26's solution is a good one.  Another alternative, if you want to set up a method that can be overloaded with any user-supplied function or with another of the object's methods, is build a custom descriptor.  This descriptor can be used as a decorator (analogous to @classmethod or @staticmethod); and it allows you to store a function in an instance's dictionary, and returns it as a method:

```
import types

class overloadable(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._default_func = func
        self._name = func.__name__

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        func = obj.__dict__.get(self._name, self._default_func)
        return types.MethodType(func, obj, type)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if hasattr(value, 'im_func'): value = value.im_func
        obj.__dict__[self._name] = value

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        del obj.__dict__[self._name]
```

Now we can just decorate a function with "@overloadable":

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def doStuff(self, string):
        print 'do stuff:', string
    @overloadable
    def overLoaded(self, arg):
        print 'default behavior:', arg
```

And it'll just do the right thing when we overload it for a given instance:

```
>>> sc = SomeClass()
>>> sc.overLoaded("test string")    # Before customization
default behavior: test string

>>> sc.overLoaded = sc.doStuff      # Customize
>>> sc.overLoaded("test string")
do stuff: test string

>>> del sc.overLoaded               # Revert to default behavior
>>> sc.overLoaded("test string")
default behavior: test string
```